# Querying with Datatable a combination of multiple select in one row

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I'll proceed to explain by showing you a simple example

```
table NAMES
 ID_NAMES
 NAME

table AGES
 ID_AGES
 AGE
```

this is my query

```
SELECT 
( 
  select NAME
  from NAMES 
  where ID_NAME=1
) as thisismyname,
(
  select AGE
  from AGES
  where ID_AGE=50
) as thisiymyage
```

I'm expecting results like

```
thisismyname, thisismyage
```

I'm perfectly aware that it's completely stupid, because I could do a join and get an easy query, but there is NO links between tables and this will be a result of a combination of 50 select, not just two.

It's working, but I want a DataTable where I can query with just using

```
 mydatatable[0]["thisismyname"]
```

Actually it's giving me results only with an ExecuteScalar, and SQLDataReader gives me empty DataTable

```
using (var conn = Connection)
{
  DbCommand mycommand = GetCommand(conn, sql);
  DbDataReader reader = mycommand.ExecuteReader();
  dt.Load(reader);
  reader.Close();
  conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Your example does not make sense.  There is a link between the tables, namely, `id`.  I think you should post another question with a better explanation of the problem (it is unfair to @NickBray to modify this question, since that might render his answer incorrect).

Comment: I've invented the example, let me modify the id columns then

Comment: . . you should really ask another question.  Nick's answer is correct based on the original formulation.

Comment: his second query did the trick ;)

Answer (score 2):

This should be done in SQL.  If you have a problem then you can try to do distinct.  You don't need indexes on your tables to join them.

```
  select distinct n.NAME, a.AGE
  from NAMES n
     JOIN AGES a on a.ID = n.ID
  where n.ID=1
```

You could create some custom code where you get two data tables and merge them somehow, but I don't think that it would be a good solution.

If for some reason the ID's on AGES and NAMES are different and cannot be joined, then you should probably create a SQL query with 2 parameters AgeId and NameId:

```
  select distinct n.NAME, a.AGE
  from NAMES n
        cross join AGES a
  where n.ID=@nameId
    and a.ID=@ageId
```

Comment: . . You should be using `cross join` rather than the comma in the `from` clause.  The "," is ancient SQL syntax.